# Find, decode and replace all base64 values in text file

Tags: python, sql, regex, sed, base64

I have a SQL dump file that contains text with html links like:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://blahblah.org/kb/getattachment.php?data=NHxUb3Bjb25fZGF0YS1kb3dubG9hZF9ob3d0by5wZGY=&quot;&gt;attached file&lt;/a&gt;
```

I'd like to find, decode and replace the base64 part of the text in each of these links.

I've been trying to use Python w/ regular expressions and base64 to do the job. However, my regex skills are not up to the task.

I need to select any string that starts with

```
'getattachement.php?data='
```

and ends with

```
'&quot;'
```

I then need to decode the part between 'data=' and '&quot' using base64.b64decode()

results should look something like:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://blahblah.org/kb/4/Topcon_data-download_howto.pdf&quot;&gt;attached file&lt;/a&gt;
```

I think the solution will look something like:

```
import re
import base64
with open('phpkb_articles.sql') as f:
    for line in f:
        re.sub(some_regex_expression_here, some_function_here_to_decode_base64)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Answer for anyone who's interested.

```
import re
import base64
import sys


def decode_base64(s):
    """
    Method to decode base64 into ascii
    """
    # fix escaped equal signs in some base64 strings
    base64_string = re.sub('%3D', '=', s.group(1))
    decodedString = base64.b64decode(base64_string)

    # substitute '|' for '/'
    decodedString = re.sub('\|', '/', decodedString)

    # escape the spaces in file names
    decodedString = re.sub(' ', '%20', decodedString)

    # print 'assets/' + decodedString + '&quot'  # Print for debug
    return 'assets/' + decodedString + '&quot'


count = 0

pattern = r'getattachment.php\?data=([^&]+?)&quot'

# Open the file and read line by line
with open('phpkb_articles.sql') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            # globally substitute in new file path
            edited_line = re.sub(pattern, decode_base64, line)
            # output the edited line to standard out
            sys.stdout.write(edited_line)
        except TypeError:
            # output unedited line if decoding fails to prevent corruption
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            # print line
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already have it, you just need the small pieces:

pattern: `r'data=([^&]+?)&quot'` will match anything after `data=` and before `&quot`

```
>>> pat = r'data=([^&]+?)&quot'
>>> line = '&lt;a href=&quot;http://blahblah.org/kb/getattachment.php?data=NHxUb3Bjb25fZGF0YS1kb3dubG9hZF9ob3d0by5wZGY=&quot;&gt;attached file&lt;/a&gt;'
>>> decodeString = re.search(pat,line).group(1) #because the b64 string is capture by grouping, we only want group(1)
>>> decodeString
'NHxUb3Bjb25fZGF0YS1kb3dubG9hZF9ob3d0by5wZGY='
```

you can then use `str.replace()` method as well as `base64.b64decode()` method to finish the rest. I dont want to just write your code for you but this should give you a good idea of where to go.