# Facing problem to decode ?UTF-8?B?ZnVjayDwn5CO?=! type in subject. Using IMAP and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, imap

Need to get real string instead of that encoded string. Few subjects are proper in string format but few are in this encoded format, I don't know how to solve it.

How can I decode the string and print the decoded part of the subject?

```
FROM_EMAIL  = "my_id@gmail.com"
FROM_PWD    = "my Password"
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT   = 993
l=['Developer','Architect','NEED','Internship','Urgent']
def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None,True)
def readmail():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
    mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
    mail.select('inbox')
    type, data = mail.search(None, '(SINCE "20-May-2020" BEFORE "26-May-2020")')
    mail_ids = data[0]
    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    id_list=id_list[::-1]
    first_email_id = id_list[0]
    latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
    for byte_obj in id_list:
        typ, data = mail.fetch(byte_obj, '(RFC822)' )
        raw=email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
        msg=get_body(raw)
        s='' 

        s=raw['SUBJECT']
        s1=raw['Date']
        print(s)
readmail()
```

output:

```
Winner announcement!  Amazon Kindle Oasis.

[FREE WEBINAR] Natural Language Processing for Beginners

Godrej 24 | Get Rs. 2 Lakh Gold Voucher | 2 & 3 BHK at Rs. 83 Lakh*

=?UTF-8?B?TGFzdCBkYXkgdG8gc2F2ZSEgUG9wdWxhciBjb3Vyc2VzIGFzIGw=?=
        =?UTF-8?B?b3cgYXMg4oK5NDU1?=

Panda just uploaded a video

Vernix Gamerz just uploaded a video
```

Comment: Email.header has functions for decoding these, but if you use the new versions of the email parsing functions in 3.6, this will be done automatically.

Comment: There is a library with parsed emails: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 1):

Most of your question has been answered here:

[Find, decode and replace all base64 values in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487243/find-decode-and-replace-all-base64-values-in-text-file)

In order to better understand your example I have some additional information:

Part of your subject lines are encoded in the `base64`-Format.

Take the following **part of** your string `s=raw['SUBJECT']` as example

`=?UTF-8?B?TGFzdCBkYXkgdG8gc2F2ZSEgUG9wdWxhciBjb3Vyc2VzIGFzIGw=?=
        =?UTF-8?B?b3cgYXMg4oK5NDU1?=`

The structure is as follows:

First you have:

```
?UTF-8?B?
```

Then comes the encoded string:

```
TGFzdCBkYXkgdG8gc2F2ZSEgUG9wdWxhciBjb3Vyc2VzIGFzIGw
```

Followed by

```
=?
```

Converting the encoded string from `base64` to `UTF-8` gives you the text:

```
Last day to save! Popular courses as l
```

You can verify this under https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: How to convert base64 to string then?

Comment: Yes. You could do that after you have split your string into encoded and unencoded parts using a regular expression that I have provided  for example.

Comment: can you please provide ma a small snippet coz I'm new, not much familiar too

Comment: Your problem has been solved here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487243/find-decode-and-replace-all-base64-values-in-text-file)